# ACL Package for Lumen 5.1

Tags: package, acl, recommendation-engine, lumen

I'm looking for a package that would enable my project to have ACL functionality. So far I've seen https://github.com/signes-pl/laravel-acl and http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/docs/1.0/acl but I haven't seen any comparison of pros and cons (i.e. which is faster?). Or is there any other package that you can recommend?